# Performance tuning of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have a query which takes a long time to run. It is probably because I used too many `isnulls` in the join condition. How can I optimise it by removing the `isnull`?

Is there any alternate way without updating the table? The query is given below:

```
 select pos.C_id
    ,pos.s_id
    ,pos.A_id
    ,pos.Ad_id
    ,pos.Pr_id
    ,pos.prog_id
    ,pos.port_id
    ,pos.o_type
    ,pos.o_id
    ,pos.s_id
    ,pos.c_id
    ,pos.s_type_id
    ,pos.s_type
    ,pos.e_date
    ,pos.mv
    ,0 is_pub
    , 1 is_adj           
    ,pos.is_unsup
    ,getdate() date
    ,getdate() timestamp
    from #temp pos
    left join acc c with(nolock) ON pos._id = c.c_id
    AND pos.account_id = c.account_id
    AND isnull(pos.Pr_id,0) = isnull(c.pr_id,0)
    AND isnull(pos.prog_id,0) = isnull(c.prog_id,0)
    AND isnull(pos.port_id,0) = isnull(c.port_id,0)
    and isnull(pos.style_type_id,0)=isnull(c.s_type_id,0)
    AND pos.s_id = c._id
    AND pos.c_id = c.c_id
    AND pos.s_type = c.s_type
    AND pos.is_unsup = c.is_uns
    AND pos.is_pub = 1
    where c.a_id is null
```

Comment: Check your execution plan and its suggestions. May be creating a covering index could help in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
AND (pos.Pr_id = c.pr_id OR (pos.Pr_id IS NULL AND c.pr_id IS NULL))
```

instead of

```
AND ISNULL(pos.Pr_id,0) = ISNULL(c.pr_id,0)
```

IS NULL is more efficient than ISNULL

Answer (score 1):

What about the query below

```
 select pos.C_id
    ,pos.s_id
    ,pos.A_id
    ,pos.Ad_id
    ,pos.Pr_id
    ,pos.prog_id
    ,pos.port_id
    ,pos.o_type
    ,pos.o_id
    ,pos.s_id
    ,pos.c_id
    ,pos.s_type_id
    ,pos.s_type
    ,pos.e_date
    ,pos.mv
    ,0 is_pub
    , 1 is_adj           
    ,pos.is_unsup
    ,getdate() date
    ,getdate() timestamp
    from #temp pos
    left join acc c with(nolock) ON pos._id = c.c_id
    AND pos.account_id = c.account_id
    AND pos.Pr_id = c.pr_id
    AND pos.prog_id = c.prog_id
    AND pos.port_id = c.port_id
    and pos.style_type_id=c.s_type_id
    AND pos.s_id = c._id
    AND pos.c_id = c.c_id
    AND pos.s_type = c.s_type
    AND pos.is_unsup = c.is_uns
    AND pos.is_pub = 1
    where c.a_id is null
union all
 select pos.C_id
    ,pos.s_id
    ,pos.A_id
    ,pos.Ad_id
    ,pos.Pr_id
    ,pos.prog_id
    ,pos.port_id
    ,pos.o_type
    ,pos.o_id
    ,pos.s_id
    ,pos.c_id
    ,pos.s_type_id
    ,pos.s_type
    ,pos.e_date
    ,pos.mv
    ,0 is_pub
    , 1 is_adj           
    ,pos.is_unsup
    ,getdate() date
    ,getdate() timestamp
    from #temp pos
    left join acc c with(nolock) ON pos._id = c.c_id
    AND pos.account_id = c.account_id
    AND pos.s_id = c._id
    AND pos.c_id = c.c_id
    AND pos.s_type = c.s_type
    AND pos.is_unsup = c.is_uns
    AND pos.is_pub = 1
    where c.a_id is null
    AND pos.Pr_id is null AND  c.pr_id is null
    AND pos.prog_id is null AND  c.prog_id is null
    AND pos.port_id is null AND  c.port_id is null
    and pos.style_type_id is null AND c.s_type_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to set a clustered index on your temp table `#temp`, if not present sql-server will provide a default hash-based index for joins, and it is not performant for large tables.

If any of all that id's columns you have in your `#temp` table is a unique key you really need to create a clustered index on it:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_temp ON #temp (YourIDColumn);
```

If you have not a key column in `#temp` add an identity primary key to it in this way:

1) if you use `SELECT INTO` approach to create `#temp`, change

```
select *
into #temp
from YourQuery
```

in

```
select IDENTITY (int, 1,1) ThisIsTheKey, *
into #temp
from YourQuery

-- and then add the index
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_temp ON #temp (ThisIsTheKey);
```

1) if you use `CREATE TABLE` + `INSERT INTO` approach, simply add the column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
    ThisIsTheKey INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ..
    ..
    -- ALL YOUR OTHER COLUMNS
    ..
    ..
)
```

Don't rely on covering non clustered indexes because the optimizer will likely not use them because you are selecting too many columns.

First test with the clustered index, then if you need further optimization you can try to add some specific non clustered index.